# Confusion with indexes in this Stochastic D.E

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I need to solve for 
$dS_n = 2S_ndt + 3S_ndB_t$ with $S_0 = 2$

If I were to substitute Ito's formula, would it appear in this form:?

$d \ln S_n = f'(S_n)dS_n + \frac{1}{2} \sigma ^2 (S_n) f''(S_n)dt$

Should $dt$ be $dn$?

The notation confuses me.

Comment: As it is written now, the SDE doesn't make sense at all... sure that there are no typos in it?

Comment: My initial thought as well @saz, that there must be typos in it. 
It would make more sense as

$dS_n = 2S_ndn + 3S_ndB_n$ ?

Comment: Yes, it would. (Or, using standard notation: $dS_t = 2S_t \, dt + 3S_t \, dB_t$.)

Comment: thank you for confirming my suspicions @saz

Answer (score 0):

Indeed by https://almostsuremath.com/2010/01/25/the-generalized-ito-formula/

we have

$$df(S)=f'(S)dS+\frac{1}{2}f''(S)d[S]$$

$$=\frac{1}{S}S(2dt+3dB)+\frac{-1}{2}\frac{1}{S^2}(3S)^2dt$$

$$=(\frac{-5}{2})dt+3dB.$$